# Transcribir Javascript a TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Existe alguna herramienta que convierta **Javascript Nativo** a **Typescript**?

Tengo el siguiente código.

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function (s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
        }
        , format = function (s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                return c[p];
            })
        };
    return function (table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table);
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML};
       // window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        var link = document.createElement("a");
                    link.download = name+"funco.xls";
                    link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
                    link.click();
    }
})();
```

**Gracias!**

**Código actual en TS**

```
namespace Lib.Utilities.ReportUtilities {

    export function exportToExcel(tableId: string, name: string, filename : string) {
        let uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(decodeURI(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function (table, name, filename) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            let ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
            let link = document.createElement("a");
            link.download = name + "test.xls";
            link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
            link.click();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y lo has transcrito? ¿Nos muestras lo que tienes en TS para ver donde falla tu traducción?

Comment: Con que propósito quieres hacer esto? Sabes que TypeScript transpila a JavaScript?  Has intentado hacerlo tu a mano, que errores has tenido? Son pocas lineas.

Comment: Si entiendo que se transpila. El objetivo es poder modificarlo en un futuro, entenderlo mejor y manipularlo con más facilidad,  mi sistema esta orientado a objetos.

Comment: Te dejo una joya: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8zpuxuGlqU&t=2342s Justo en la demo sobre migración. Disfruta :D